# Хороший обзор по стандартной библиотеке Python

Tags: python

Где можно прочитать о пакетах с которми поставляется питон, дабы иметь хорошее представление что питон может из коробки, а что нет?

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/index.html

Answer (score 1):

В официальной документации есть раздел по [стандартной библиотеке](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/index.html). На русском есть книга Дэвид Бизли "Python подробный справочник".